# Laravel fetch files storage with sub-directory

Tags: php, laravel, directory, storage

In my laravel 7.x application all the uploaded files are stored in `storage/app/public/<user-uuid-as-directory>`

For example:
`storage/app/public/a6d4b3cb-a823-11eb-bfce-fcaa149efd09/72c2881d-a824-11eb-bfce-fcaa149efd09.png`

When I am trying to access the file, I am getting `404` error.

filesystem.php

```php
... 

'images' => [
   'driver'     => 'local',
   'root'       => storage_path('app/public'),
   'url'        => env('APP_URL') . '/images',
   'visibility' => 'public',
],

...
```

some.blade.php

```php
$uuid = auth()->user()->token; // 'a6d4b3cb-a823-11eb-bfce-fcaa149efd09'

@foreach($images as $image)
    <img src="{{ Storage::disk('images')->url($uuid . '/' . $image) }}" />
@endforeach
```

What am I doing wrong here..?

Comment: Try changing `images` to `storage` in `url` of your `filesystem.php`.

Comment: Also clear your config cache with `php artisan config:clear`.

Comment: Tried, not working.

Comment: If you put the url directly in the browser `your-domain/storage/a6d4b3cb-a823-11eb-bfce-fcaa149efd09/72c2881d-a824-11eb-bfce-fcaa149efd09.png`. Is the image loaded?

Comment: Also, did you create the symbolic link from public/storage to storage/app/public?

Comment: No, browser link doesn't work and Yes, symbolic link is created

Comment: Then it could be a permissions issue. Make sure the server has read permission on the storage directory and its subdirectories

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create `symbolic link` then change in filesystem.php file

```
'url'=> env('APP_URL') . '/images',
```

to be

```
'url'=> env('APP_URL') . '/storage/images',
```

I hope this help you , thanks.